# sqlite vs .mdb in a multiuser situation

Tags: sqlite, ms-access, jet

I like the ease of deployment these 2 offer compared to mysql/sql server etc.

Which scales better in terms of performance and is less prone to corruption in a multiuser environment as the number of users grows?

I have worked with access/jet but not with sqlite.

My experience with access is that it works well enough in the situations in which I use it, small, cabled, LANs but that there can be corruption problems when the network isn't rock solid. Also it doesn't seem to work at all well on wireless networks (at least for me).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to check out SqLite's 'appropriate uses' page [here](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).  It lists pros/cons of using sqlite in various scenarios.  However, it should stand up pretty well against Access, provided you're not going to use it for concurrent access from multiple processes *from multiple machines*.

MS Access has a number of limits which you may want to check out [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx), e.g. max DB size of 2GB, max 255 concurrent users, etc.  SqLite scales higher than these limits in almost all  cases I think.

EDIT: One other thing: SqLite doesn't offer password-encrypted databases as standard, whereas MS Access obviously does.  SqLite does have a [proprietary extension for encryption](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html) though, by the same developers who write SqLite:

Comment: I really should up vote this answer. The issue pointed out here is that SQLite does not support mult-users in a file share. This being the case, then the question and comparing here does not make sense. At the end of the day the poster should either install a server based system like MySQL (recommend) or they stick to the file based data engine like JET. To my knowledge, you cannot use SQLite in this manor so it not a choice nor can a comparison be made here.

Comment: @Nick thanks for the useful and informative links@Albert, you are correct but yet the impression is given that if writes are relatively rare that there shouldn't be a noticeable problem. My scenarios are networks of at most 10 simultaneous users for which Jet works very well except when there's a network issue and then the database can get corrupted and also wireless networks can cause problems.
SQLite can handle multiple simultaenous reads, but only 1 write and you can't have reads and a write at the same time.

Comment: @Albert (continued)So I'm thinking that it just might work for not-busy networks and what I suppose I am really wondering is if it would be less prone to corruption due to network problems and also able to work better on a wireless LAN? Maybe I asked the wrong question

Answer (score 4):

You are not comparing like with like, Access is a rapid application database development tool commonly using a Jet/ACE file based database. SQLite is a file based database. You would need to say which front end you intend to use to get an appropriate comparison. Access as a front-end supplies reporting tools, etc, etc.

Given that there is a tested upward path for MS Access through SQL Server Express to SQL Server for the back-end, I would suggest that Access scales better.

Comment: I understand the distinction, I should just have used the words .mdb and jet. People using Access would be the ones most familiar with Jet, hence the use of the ms-access tag. I don't use access per se just the Jet database engine and .mdb files but often I do lazily refer to the database as Access mainly because more people have heard of that rather than Jet.

Answer (score 3):

> **Why Choose Microsoft Access?**
>    Microsoft Access is the most widely used desktop database system in the world.
>    Microsoft Access is part of Microsoft Office so there is a common interface and lots of developers and support options available.
>    You can use the free Microsoft Access 2007 runtime.
>    Microsoft Access is significantly less expensive than either SQL Server or Oracle.
>    Typical development times for custom databases using a qualified consultant (such as RPT Software) are days. Doing similar development using other tools such as .net or building a web-based system would typical be multiples of the time required.
>    Third party support for Microsoft Access databases is very common. Example: interfaces to external databases etc...
>    If you need a database that serves your needs and Microsoft Access is a viable option, it is probably the fastest and least expensive way to get your goals accomplished.
>   **Why NOT to Choose Microsoft Access?**
>    You have determined that you need a web-based system.
>    You have too many concurrent users. Technical limit is 255 concurrent users, but real world limit is 10 to 80 (depending on type of application).
>    Your users are geographically spread too far and you do not want to use remote control solutions to get around this limitation.
>    You have users on Macintosh computers (consider Filemaker).
>    Your database will be too big to work with Microsoft Access. Usually if you know that something will be over a million records, you might be getting into this situation.

Source: http://www.rptsoftware.com/aboutus/microsoft_access_database/

MySQL is used with PHP mostly in LAMP environment. SQL server is used with Windows environment and both of them are comprehensive database management systems.

SQLite is a file based database system. Used mostly for storing session information (in case of android) and also used in GIS in form of spatialite.

Answer (score -1):

I have used SQLite with C# as a backend database, it works perfectly without any disturbing situation. In my application scenario, there are 5 users working on same application which uses SQLite and they have not got any trouble.